# Content arranging in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
  $title = $page_data->post_title;
  echo $content;
}
```

I want this code to be changes so i can create a one page website and show only those pages i need to show on front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `include` parameter to include only the pages you need. Note, this parameter takes an array or a comma separated string of page ID's

You can try the following to only show pages 1, 2 and 3

```
$args = array(
    'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 );
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );
// REST OF YOUR CODE
```

Comment: in array where you added 1 , 2 , 3 there will be a page id